# ImportError: cannot import name 'doc' from 'pandas.util._decorators' (C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py)

Tags: python, pandas, anaconda, importerror, pycaret

I am trying to import pycaret but this error holds me back.
How do I solve this?

[ImportError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zuvh.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I get this error when importing fbprophet. Actually this error happens when you import any package that contains pandas.

I'm trying to downgrade pandas but conda says my packages are in conflict.Probably need to reinstall anaconda to solve this.

Comment: Please explain how your answer helps the asker? Answer fields are not meant to be used as comment fields.

Comment: Update. I uninstall the pandas and rebuild it with another version then the error is gone.